# Disabling journal in AKKA persistence

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence

I'm doing a performance test to an AKKA persistent actor and I want to know the impact writing to the journal.

Simple question but I did not find anything in the documentation:

How to disable the journal from the config file? I'm looking for something like a mock or null journal plugin.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a project with a persistence plugin (journal + snapshots) that basically does not do anything but ignoring.

Of course, using this plugin will not recover after a failure, so your system will not be resilient.

This is the project: https://github.com/angelcervera/akka-persistence-nowhere

How to use it:

1. Import or add in the classpath

```scala
resolvers += "osm4scala repo" at "http://dl.bintray.com/angelcervera/maven" // If 
it's not found in the main maven repository. 
libraryDependencies += "com.acervera.akka" %% "akka-persistence-nowhere" % "1.0.1"
```

2. Overwriting your default application.conf

```
akka {
  persistence {
    journal.plugin = "disable-journal-store"
    snapshot-store.plugin = "disable-snapshot-store"
  }
}

disable-journal-store {
  class = "com.acervera.akka.persistence.nowhere.AkkaPersistenceNowhereJournal"
  plugin-dispatcher = "akka.persistence.dispatchers.default-plugin-dispatcher"
}

disable-snapshot-store {
  class = "com.acervera.akka.persistence.nowhere.AkkaPersistenceNowhereSnapshotStore"
  plugin-dispatcher = "akka.persistence.dispatchers.default-plugin-dispatcher"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there's no akka persistence plugin that just does not do anything - since it basically defeats the purpose of persistence. Note that akka-persistence uses [eventsourcing](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/persistence.html#event-sourcing) approach, so *journal* is the "main" storage, and snapshots are an optimization to speed up state recovery after actor crash/restart/etc. So you can't really disable journal completely.

The closest to what you want might be the [in-memory](https://github.com/dnvriend/akka-persistence-inmemory) persistence, or [Local LevelDB](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/persistence.html#local-leveldb-journal) persistence.

Also, there's a [list of community-built plugins for persistence](https://index.scala-lang.org/search?topics=akka-persistence&_ga=2.179340708.1869502623.1561432275-1053662782.1548407683) - you might be able to find something that matches your use case.

However, I would recommend testing the performance of the persistence with the actual persistence plugin you'd be using in production - results vary across different persistence backends (e.g. Cassandra vs. DynamoDb vs. JDBC vs. Mongo, etc.)

Comment: Yes, this is what I used to do. The point is that I want to know the performance of updating the state of the actor and penalty paid because AKKA (for example, sync the cluster, serialization, create events from commands, etc.) but I want to remove the journal because I know that there is a big impact in this part.

Comment: @angelcervera I guess at this point you have two options: (1) accept the overhead the in-memory plugin gives as a good enough approximation or (2) go on and implement the noop persistence plugin yourself (there's a [guide](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/persistence-journals.html) on how to do that)

Comment: I will try the second one.